# JSON assertion - Assert multiple response values

Tags: json, jmeter, assertion

```
{
                "id": 280,
                "name": "Kru",
                "description": "alphabetic description",
                "status": 2,
                "condition_type": "1",
                "created_at": "2019-02-05T14:43:04.000Z",
                "updated_at": "2019-02-05T14:43:04.000Z"
            },
            {
                "id": 25,
                "name": "Krut",
                "description": "abckdk eje  jw s",
                "status": 1,
                "condition_type": "0",
                "created_at": "2019-02-05T11:11:02.000Z",
                "updated_at": "2019-02-05T11:11:02.000Z"
            }
```

I'm trying to assert above JSON response. My test case passes if the response has status value 1 as well as 2 and fail otherwise. Right now, i can only assert one value at a time. How can i assert two values? Thank you in advance. [JSON assertion I implemented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFTka.png)

Comment: Loop with the foreach controller about the objects in this response...

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) as a child of the request which returns the above JSON
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(prev.getResponseDataAsString(), '$..status').each { status ->
       if (!(1..2).contains(status)) {
           AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
           AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('Comparison failed, got: ' + status)
       }
   }
   ```
3. That's it, the above code will verify each `status` value and assess whether it is between `1` and `2` inclusively. In case of unexpected status the relevant Sampler(s) in the assertion's [scope](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/UserManual/ScopingRules) will be marked as failed:

   [image]

   Check out [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial) article for more information on the concept of code-based assertions in JMeter.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I needed exactly what you explained lately,
So I've been playing with it a little and this ^ worked for me :)
(order matters of course)